# Setup browser-sync to serve routes from absolute directories on windows

Tags: browser-sync

I am trying to serve certain routes from absolute directories I have tried different things like this...

```
server: 
{
    routes:
    {
       "/vendor":"x:\\js\\static\\vendor",
       "/assets":"/temp/assets"
    }
}
```

but browser-sync always returns 404 for resources located in those routes.

```
$ curl localhost:3000/assets/test.css
Cannot GET /assets/test.css
```

I believe I am missing something very trivial, but can't see what.

Comment: did you find a solution?